# Erro em WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Situação:

1. Usuário tem 2 itens no valor de R$ 200,00 no carrinho
2. Usuário ao acessar a pagina inicial, ao olhar ao carrinho visualiza somente 1 item no valor de R$85,00

Código utilizada para printar o carrinho com os valores respectivos:

```
                            <p>
                                Meu Carrinho<br>
                                <?php echo wp_kses_post( WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal() ); ?> <span class="count"><?php echo wp_kses_data( sprintf( _n( '%d item', '%d items', WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count(), 'storefront' ), WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ) );?></span>
                            </p>
```

OBS: Somente na página inicial.

*

Tema: Storefront

Plugin geral: WooCommerce

Wordpress Versão 4.9

*

Comment: Não seria mais fácil abrir a *issue* no projeto oficial?

Comment: Não sei se é um bug, ou um erro de interpretação e implementação meu, acha melhor reportar no projeto oficial?